# Library AVFoundation and dump photo on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible for AVFoundation framework to create APP, which can do
temporary screenshots/photos every amount of time I demand or after
focus being set? Pictures shouldn't be saved. I want to create a
function which scans for QR code on the temporary picture, and if it is
possible for this function to enable ViewController? If it isn't
possible with help of AVFoundation framework, could you point me the way
of doing this? I'd be grateful for every piece of advice

Comment: Can't you use existing QR code libraries/SDKs that do all this for you?

Comment: @meaning-matters I have already purchased a library that will allow me to read QR Code, and more.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to live analyse by:

`AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];`

Then you need a AVCaptureDevice, AVCaptureDeviceInput and a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

In the callback function from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput convert the CVPixelBufferRef to a CIImage.

Then use CIDetector to extract your QRCodes.

When it comes to the question "function to enable ViewController" I don't really understand that part so I can't help you there.

/Anders